# Creating helper to minify JS; What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
public class JavaScriptHelper
{
    public HelperResult Minify(Func<HelperResult> code)
    {
        return new HelperResult(writer => writer.Write(JavaScriptCompressor.Compress(code().ToString())));
    }
}

@section Script
{
@JavaScriptHelper.Minify(
@<script>
    (function ($, b) {
        $(function () {
            $("#upload").bind("submit", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log("going");
                $(this).ajaxSubmit(function (result) {
                    if (!b.ajaxFailure(result, true)) {
                        console.log(result);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    })(jQuery, b);
</script>)
}
```

Comment: I hope the tags I added are correct. If not, please change them back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The helper needs to be static and Razor will pass in `Func<dynamic, HelperResult>` rather than just `Func<HelperResult>`. Also, you won't want to pass `<script></script>` to the minifier so move them outside the `JavaScriptHelper.Minify(...)` call and then wrap the content with `<text></text>` so Razor knows how to parse it. Try this:

```
public class JavaScriptHelper
{
        public static HelperResult Minify(Func<dynamic, HelperResult> code)
        {
            return new HelperResult(writer => writer.Write(JavaScriptCompressor.Compress(code(null).ToString())));
        }
}

@section Script
{
    <script>
    @JavaScriptHelper.Minify(
    @<text>
    (function ($, b) {
        $(function () {
            $('#upload').bind('submit', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log('going');
                $(this).ajaxSubmit(function (result) {
                    if (!b.ajaxFailure(result, true)) {
                        console.log(result);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    })(jQuery, b);

    </text>)
    </script>

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using a partial action though